# Do I need to insert a value to a foreign key in SQL?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

Simple question.

If i had a table *users* which contains columns like *username*, *password*, and an auto incrementing *id* which is the primary key.
And another table called *names* which contains *first_name*, *middle_name*, *last_name* and a foreign key called *user_id* which references the id in the users table.

Do I have to insert a value to that foreign key? Or SQL will automatically copy the value of the *id* in the *users* table?

Another follow up question, What is the data type of the *user_id* field in the *names* table?

Comment: Standard SQL does not support auto-incrementing values so you will have to name your SQL product e.g. in Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) if your create a `VIEW` (query object, QueryDef, whatever) joining the two tables and insert into the `VIEW` then it will automatically copy the autonumber value across. But this may not help you if you are not using Access :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to insert the foreign key. When you insert a record into the *names* table, SQL will not automatically be able to know which *user* the *names* record is referring to.

As user_id is referring to an id field that is auto-incrementing it is most likely going to be an integer field.